# Running google actions on raspberrypi using google assistant SDK

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Is it possible to run google actions on raspberrypi running Google Assistant SDK? I was able to run my app in test mode, but unable to run any other app except my test app? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run any action using the push to talk/gRPC sample, although I am less sure about the hotword/library sample.